# Check if DST is set for specific date and time

Tags: c, unix, datetime

i am trying to check, with plain c, whether the DST is set on a specific date and time. i have tested gmtime and localtime, but these functions only take care of the current system DST.

Thanks for your advice.
thomas

Comment: Are you referring to Daylight Saving Time ?

Comment: It's a hard problem in general; adding computers doesn't make it a whole lot easier. Depending on the locale, the DST period may be determined in the preceding year. As a result, in those locales it's impossible to check whether the DST will apply AT ALL for a date too far in the future. The past would similarly require historic DST dates.

Comment: Setting DST is a political decision. It is impossible to determine if DST is set on a specific date and time (and place) in the future. I don't really know how it works in C for the past, but I hope the library simply ignores DST ... in a thousand years, the DST table will be larger than the compiler itself!

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `zic` and `zdump`. Use man for more information.

When I needed to know DST without holding the 6MB of compiled data I modified zic's code to create a samller table with the required data.